# Meaning of 方 in 「質問のある方はどうぞ」

Tags: meaning

In the sentence

> 質問のある**方**はどうぞ

what is the meaning of 方?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「質問{しつもん}のある方{かた}はどうぞ。」

「方{かた}」 in this context is the honorific/respectful form of 「人{ひと}」 ("person(s)").  The meaning is the same for both.

> "Those who have questions, please (ask)!"